# Converting existing MySQL rails app to use Postgres: 'all pooled connections were in use'

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I'm converting a project from MySQL to PostgreSQL. After configuring it, when I run `rake db:create` or `rake db:migrate` I get the error: `ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError: could not obtain a connection from the pool within 5.000 seconds (waited 5.000 seconds); all pooled connections were in use`.

I tried increasing the pool to 50. Another rails project on the same machine uses PostgreSQL just fine. Any ideas what might be going ?

The full stack trace is:

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError: could not obtain a connection from the pool within 5.000 seconds (waited 5.000 seconds); all pooled connections were in use
/Users/tonyporteous/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@citydash/gems/activerecord-5.1.6.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:202:in `block in wait_poll'
/Users/tonyporteous/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@citydash/gems/activerecord-5.1.6.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:193:in `loop'
/Users/tonyporteous/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@citydash/gems/activerecord-5.1.6.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:193:in `wait_poll'
/Users/tonyporteous/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@citydash/gems/activerecord-5.1.6.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:154:in `internal_poll'
/Users/tonyporteous/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@citydash/gems/activerecord-5.1.6.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:278:in `internal_poll'
/Users/tonyporteous/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@citydash/gems/activerecord-5.1.6.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:148:in `block in poll'
/Users/tonyporteous/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@citydash/gems/activerecord-5.1.6.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:158:in `synchronize'
/Users/tonyporteous/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@citydash/gems/activerecord-5.1.6.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:148:in `poll'
/Users/tonyporteous/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@citydash/gems/activerecord-5.1.6.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:747:in `acquire_connection'
/Users/tonyporteous/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@citydash/gems/activerecord-5.1.6.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:500:in `checkout'
/Users/tonyporteous/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@citydash/gems/activerecord-5.1.6.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:374:in `connection'
/Users/tonyporteous/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@citydash/gems/activerecord-5.1.6.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:931:in `retrieve_connection'
/Users/tonyporteous/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@citydash/gems/activerecord-5.1.6.1/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:116:in `retrieve_connection'
/Users/tonyporteous/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@citydash/gems/activerecord-5.1.6.1/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:88:in `connection'
/Users/tonyporteous/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@citydash/gems/activerecord-5.1.6.1/lib/active_record/schema_migration.rb:20:in `table_exists?'
/Users/tonyporteous/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@citydash/gems/activerecord-5.1.6.1/lib/active_record/schema_migration.rb:24:in `create_table'
/Users/tonyporteous/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@citydash/gems/activerecord-5.1.6.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1125:in `initialize'
/Users/tonyporteous/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@citydash/gems/activerecord-5.1.6.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1007:in `new'
/Users/tonyporteous/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@citydash/gems/activerecord-5.1.6.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1007:in `up'
/Users/tonyporteous/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@citydash/gems/activerecord-5.1.6.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:985:in `migrate'
/Users/tonyporteous/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@citydash/gems/activerecord-5.1.6.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:171:in `migrate'
/Users/tonyporteous/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@citydash/gems/activerecord-5.1.6.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:58:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/tonyporteous/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@citydash/gems/rake-12.3.2/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/tonyporteous/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@citydash/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'
/Users/tonyporteous/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@citydash/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

The config file section looks like this:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  # For details on connection pooling, see Rails configuration guide
  # https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
  pool: <%%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: projectx_development
```

I added the gem like this:

```
gem 'pg', '>= 0.18', '< 2.0'
```

Answer (score 3):

Problem solved: Was caused by an error in the database.yml file:

```
pool: <%%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
```

should be

```
pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
```

which was (I guess) causing a pool size of 0 to draw from.